# Make opacity 100 when an element is reached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for help, I am doing a project but and for it I am making a website to present it on. I have made a (red coloured) nav bar that covers the top 100 pixels of my website. Under it I have multiple containers that have text, images and a video. When scrolling, I would love for all these containers to go to 100 opacity i.e. disappear when they reach the nav.
In other words make the nav the top layer of the website and any container, that when scrolling down, that reaches it, it would not go over it and cover it as I have links in my nav bar. Also, this is not urgent, but if I wanted those links to go to a certain part of the current page I am on, how would I do that?
Disclaimer: CSS would be most appropriate for my project, if not possible, that's ok.
All help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Here is the JSFiddle of the website: https://jsfiddle.net/gmsrbh70/

```
<header>
        <nav> 
            <div class='title'><h1><a href='index.html'>Computer Science Project</a></h1></div>
        <ul>
     <li> <a href= '#section1'> Introduction</a></li>
     <li> <a href= '#section2'> About </a></li>
     <li> <a href= '#section3'> Graphs</a></li>
         </ul>    
    </nav> 
        
    </header>
    
    <div class='task'>
    <h1> What was the task assigned?</h1>
        <p>The Create an innovative computational artefact which you feel could be used to address any or some  of the issues raised in the context of this brief and report on the work and process involved.</p>
    </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: So why is the nav bar not just set to go over the content? Add `z-index: 1;` to the header

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2.3

Comment: @epascarello thank you very much! That worked, very greatly appreciated.